# How to consume a service from a scheduled task being both part of the same application?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .net core webapi with some services. This application can also run scheduled tasks in the background using [Quartz for .Net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) and now I need one of those tasks to consume some of the services within the api.

I know it's a bad practice to consume a service from within another, but a scheduled task is not a service. So is this ok? Should I simply use HttpClient to connect to the current running api?

Comment: If the projects are in the same solution I think it is entirely appropriate to use the services directly instead of doing it through the client in a roundabout way. Especially with scheduled tasks and workers. You will need to  [add a reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019#:~:text=To%20add%20a%20reference%2C%20right,node%20and%20select%20Add%20%3E%20Reference.) to the API in your scheduled task worker. If this doesn't get you off the ground, I recommend posting code so we can help you better.

Comment: @StiyAle If I understand correctly what you're saying is I need to include the dependency between projects to be able to call directly the methods of the services from the task. Is that right? If so, how can I access the instance of the controller to call the method?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you only add your services as a dependency. Your controllers should not be doing any work and this is a great example why. I am unfamiliar with Quartz, but if it is compatible with .net Dependency injection you would just add `.configureServices((hostContext, services)` to your Program.cs of the worker project and add any services from you other project. I may have an easier time if you post the code for your worker (program.cs especially). Then I can post a proper answer with examples.